# ordering / creating a ranking of a list of preferences with overlaps

Tags: javascript, sorting, ranking

I am searching for a simple algorithm / javascript implementation for the following problem:

I have an object with the following structure:

```
preference = {1:4,2:3,3:2,4:1}
```

The object represents the preference of four people (1,2,3,4) about their preference whether to decide first, second, third, or last.

In this case, this is simply:
Person 1 wants to go last (4),
person 2 wants to go third (3),
person 3 wants to go second (2),
person 4 wants to go first (1)

Yet, it can also happen that people have the same / overlapping preferences, e.g.:

```
preference = {1:1,2:1,3:1,4:1} // everybody wants to first
preference = {1:1,2:1,3:4,4:4} // some want to go first, some want to go last
```

Yet, only one person can take one spot in the chain – there can not be any overlaps.
In this case, the order needs to be reassigned based on the following rules:

let's assume two people want to go first and two people want to go second;

– then, randomly determine an order for the people who want to go first. The 'winner' can go first, the other one goes second

– since the second place is now also taken, randomly determine the third place out of all people that initially wanted to go second. The winner can go third, the other one goes last

In the end, I need an object with an assigned order based on these rules;
e.g.

preference = {1:1,2:3,3:3,4:1} –> final_order = {1:1,2:3,3:4,4:2}

Do you know a simple way to implement such an algorithm in javascript?
(pseudo-code would also already help me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the wanted preferences and reorder the preferences by iterating all places.

With `preference` of

```
{ 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 1 }
```

`temp` has this content

```
[
    undefined, /* sparse */
    [
        1,
        4
    ],
    undefined, /* sparse */
    [
        2,
        3
    ]
]
```

The following iteration omits spars elements and visits only the two arrays.

And because of the random selection the result is not predictable, but in wanted order.

```js
function adjustPreference(preference) {
    let temp = [],
        t = 1;
    
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        (temp[preference[i]] = temp[preference[i]] || []).push(i);
    }
    
    temp.forEach(persons => {
        while (persons.length) {
            const random = persons.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * persons.length), 1)[0];
            preference[random] = t++;
        }
    });
    
    return preference;
}

console.log(adjustPreference({ 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 1 }));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I am not very familiar with javascript syntax, I have to admit. What is the ??= operator? I get an error message for the function there (line 4).
If I replace it with a "=", I get an output and it seems to reassign the third position in this example, but does not reassign the first position. Maybe I am doing something wrong?
Also, for other scenarios, it seems to not reassign any positions. For example: 
adjustPreference({ 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4 }) (in this case the positions 1-4 would need to be randomly assigned, as everybody wants to go last).

Comment: replace `temp[preference[i]] ??= []` with an [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
 with `temp[preference[i]] = temp[preference[i]] || []`

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much!